# MySQL, Select records based on values in JSON array

Tags: mysql, json, database, select, mysql-5.7

I'm still pretty new to handling JSON fields in MySQL. All the solutions I've come across deal with objects that have key/values; unable to find one that handles JSON arrays.

Anyways, what I want to do is to be able to select all rows where the `interestIds` contain `2` in them. How do I do that? Thanks.

Users table

```
+----+-------------+
| id | interestIds |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | [1, 2]      |
|  2 | [3, 2]      |
|  3 | [2, 4]      |
+----+-------------+
```

Sample test query:

```
SET @userId = 2;
SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE @userId IN JSON_CONTAINS(@user, interestIds, '$[1]');
```

I am confused as how to use the `JSON_*` functions; not sure what to put for the 3rd parameter...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following solution, using [`JSON_CONTAINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(interestIds, '2') = 1;
```

The third (optional) paramater `path` gives you the posibility to use this function only on a specific part of your `JSON` value. So the following example checks if `2` is the second value of the array:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(interestIds, '2', '$[1]') = 1;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=412502d0301f769fa73ae158be19d213)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) which returns path to element you are searching, or null if not found:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(interestids, 'one', '2') IS NOT NULL
```

<kbd>**[Live Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hcD75dGZYnbF6s94PExwfD/0)**</kbd>

If you're storing many-to-many relationship using simple JSON array, there are better ways to do it. Consider creating `user_interest` table and doing it the right and simpler way. That is if your JSON actually looks like you have shown us and does not contain dynamic key-value pairs.

Comment: The question contains JSON where the interestIds are array of integers not strings. JSON_SEARCH does not work on integers

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> select id 
from users 
where JSON_CONTAINS(interestIds, "2","$");
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
3 rows in set (0.0015 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your select to `JSON_ARRAYAGG`

Like:

```sql
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(....)) FROM table....
```

Comment: only suppor above `5.7.22`